# Unity app hangs when subscribing to Firebase Event

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am building a small test app using Unity to learn Firebase and Dynamic Linking. I have imported the Dynamic Links SDK and the google-services json file.

In my Script, I am attempting to subscribe to the event "DynamicLinkReceived" but adding that line of code

```
DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += ReceivedDeepLink;
```

causes the Android app to hang on a black screen when it loads. When I run the app in Unity, it doesn't hang or produce any errors. Here is the method that should be called on that event:

```
void ReceivedDeepLink(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var dynamicLinkEventArgs = args as ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs;
    Debug.LogFormat("Received dynamic link {0}",
                    dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString);

    inputBottom.text = dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happened because you call

```
DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += ReceivedDeepLink;
```

while `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()` is still in progress.

you can update fire-base to 5.2.1 where they already throw exception in such case.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#5.1.0

first initialize firebase and if `(dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)` you can subscribe to DynamicLink

```
void InitializeFirebaseAndStart() {
    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available) {

            DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += ReceivedDeepLink;

        } else {
            Debug.LogError(
                "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
        }
    });
}
```